# Am getting operand clash error when running a datawarehouse compatible script

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Hi I am getting an error like this: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int.

Below is my query which I am running on a SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE val.census_last_month
WITH(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
,   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
 AS
  SELECT
    dt_mydate                                                                       AS dt_census,
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT encounter_id)
     FROM prod.encounter
     WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient' AND (ts_admit BETWEEN dt_mydate - 30 AND dt_mydate) AND
           (ts_discharge IS NULL OR ts_discharge > dt_mydate))                      AS census,
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT encounter_id)
     FROM prod.encounter
     WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient' AND cast(ts_admit AS DATE) = dt_mydate)     AS admits,
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT encounter_id)
     FROM prod.encounter
     WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient' AND cast(ts_discharge AS DATE) = dt_mydate) AS discharges
  FROM ref.calendar_day
  WHERE ref.calendar_day.dt_mydate BETWEEN (cast(getdate() as date) - 30) AND cast(getdate() as date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dateadd function. See details here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this script, however can you confirm the datatypes starting "ts_" are dates stored as integers in the format `yyyyMMdd` and datatypes starting "dt_" are `DATE`?

Based on these assumptions, this is my attempted rewrite:

```
SELECT dt_mydate AS dt_census,
    (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT encounter_id )
    FROM prod.encounter
    WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient' AND ( CAST( CAST( ts_admit AS CHAR(8) ) AS DATE ) BETWEEN DATEADD( day, -30, dt_mydate ) AND dt_mydate )
    AND ( ts_discharge IS NULL OR CAST( CAST( ts_discharge AS CHAR(8) ) AS DATE ) > dt_mydate)
    ) AS census,
    (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT encounter_id )
    FROM prod.encounter
    WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient' AND CAST( CAST( ts_admit AS CHAR(8) ) AS DATE ) = dt_mydate
    ) AS admits,
    (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT encounter_id )
    FROM prod.encounter
    WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient' 
    AND CAST( CAST( ts_discharge AS CHAR(8) ) AS DATE ) = dt_mydate
    ) AS discharges
FROM ref.calendar_day
WHERE ref.calendar_day.dt_mydate BETWEEN CAST ( DATEADD( day, -30, GETDATE() ) AS DATE ) AND CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE );
```

If either of my assumptions are incorrect, please let me know and I will update the script.